# Can we use stateserver sessions across multiple browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session-state

Once again the confusion related to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) documentation with respect to Session Management.

[image: Please follow the link specified above if image is not visible]

I went thru the [Session Management Article in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx), and found that it is stated in the article that - "**we can Store session-specific data on the server for use across *multiple* browser or client-device requests within the same session.**"

Can anybody tell me how is it possible. for e.g. if you have two browsers i.e. i)Firefox and ii) Internet Explorer (IE).

Now, If I am running asp.net application (which uses stateserver to manage sessions) in Firefox. And again the same application I ran through IE (without closing firefox session). Is that means that both the browser will share the same session? I guess "NO". Both the browsers will run with their own sessions, which is different from each other.

Secondly, I found that the two statements in the article are contradictory with each other. It says that - "*Session state is similar to application state, except that it is scoped to the current browser session*" and on other hand it says that - "*It Store session-specific data on the server for use across multiple browser or client-device requests within the same session*"

So, if its scope is limited to the current browser session, then how it can  be use across multiple browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little confusing, but I think you're misinterpreting the statement. They are referring to multiple ***requests***, not browsers or client-devices.

Session is indeed scoped to the current browser session, persisted with cookies or query strings.

Comment: I guess, it is clearly stated - "multiple browser request / client device request".....in either cases, my query is again the same, what do you mean by "multiple browser request"? I guess by "multiple browser request", there should be multiple browsers involved in the request not the same browser request.....

Comment: They mean multiple requests from the same browser or client device. Again, I see how you can interpret it multiple ways. It is most certainly not "requests from multiple browsers / client devices".

Comment: So - "use across multiple browser/client devices" should be interpreted as "use across multiple request from same browser or client devices"? don't you think its really confusing?

Comment: I do, yes ;) You left out the word "requests" which is the crucial noun that they are referring to. "Use across multiple browser(singular) or client device(singular) REQUESTS". Your wording is much better. Unfortunately, I do not work for Microsoft and cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, sessions are handled through cookies.  Each browser implementation (IE, Chrome) has its own cookie store.  Therefore, different browser implementations aren't going to be able to share sessions without some significant workarounds.

Multiple *instances* of **the same browser** can reference the same session because they all have access to the same cookies.  This can be described as "multiple browsers".

Comment: They didn't said "multiple instance of same browser", it is stated "multiple browser request", whereby there should be multiple browsers requesting the application.....how can we interpret "multiple browser request" with "multiple instance of same browser request"?

Comment: nothing but the clarification - is that "multiple instance of same browser" or "multiple browsers"?